# Why mean function doesn't work with ave function

Tags: r, dataframe

I would like to add a new calculated column "new" that will have the values of the mean of "snakes" per area. I tried to use the `ave` function but it didn't workd with `mean`. I tried to run the same line with `sum` and It worked, what is the reason and are there any other ways to get the desired result.

Here is my toy data frame:

```
df <- read.table(text = "snakes birds    wolfs     area
                            3        9         7 a
                            3        8         4 b
                            1        2         8 c
                            1        2         3 a
                            1        8         3 a
                            6        1         2 a
                            6        7         1 b
                            6        1         5 c   ",header = TRUE)
```

Here is the working line of code:

```
df$sum <- ave(df$snakes, df$area, FUN=sum)
df
  snakes birds wolfs area sum
1      3     9     7    a   11
2      3     8     4    b    9
3      1     2     8    c    7
4      1     2     3    a   11
5      1     8     3    a   11
6      6     1     2    a   11
7      6     7     1    b    9
8      6     1     5    c    7
```

And here is the error that I get when replacing the sum function with mean function:

```
df$avg <- ave(df$snakes, df$area, FUN=mean)
Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) : 
  object 'FUN' of mode 'function' was not found
```

Comment: I cannot replicate this error in R version `3.2.2`. Did you run this code in a clean session of R?

Comment: I run Rstudio Version 0.98.507 and R 3.1.0

Comment: Same with me.  Couldn't reproduce it on R 3.2.2 nor in R studio Version 0.99.467

Comment: I'll install R 3.2.2 to see if I have the same issue.

Comment: I also cannot replicate with R 3.1.0.

Comment: How can I do it without using the ave function?

Comment: You don't need to specify the `mean` as `ave(df$snakes, df$area)` by default gives `mean`  Have you tried `library(dplyr);df %>% group_by(area) %>% mutate(avg= mean(snakes))` or `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, avg:= mean(snakes), area]`

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I ran it on another machine with R 3.1.2 and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for the other  solutions @akrun..

Comment: Is there a way to do it with by function or another _apply family ?

Comment: You can do with `lapply` after `split` by 'area'

Comment: Thank you @akrun I'll try it too.

Comment: Try `unsplit(lapply(split(df$snakes, df$area), function(x) rep(mean(x),length(x))), df$area)`

Comment: @akrun You could post `dplyr` and `lapply` + `split` alternatives as answer.

Comment: You can save keystrokes with `unsplit(tapply(df$snakes, df$area, mean), df$area)`

Comment: Is it possible that you have in the environment an object called `mean` which is not at all a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ave` works in `R 3.2.2`, `R 3.1.0` (based on @Pascal's comment),  and in `R studio version 0.99.467`.  So, we are not sure the real reason behind the error.  As far as `mean` is concerned, we don't need to specify explicitly, as

```
ave(df$snakes, df$area)
#[1] 2.75 4.50 3.50 2.75 2.75 2.75 4.50 3.50
```

A `base R` alternative is `split/unsplit` where we `split` the 'snakes' by the 'area' column, get the `mean` of `snakes`, replicate it to `length` of the `list` element and `unsplit` by 'area'

```
unsplit(lapply(split(df$snakes, df$area), 
        function(x) rep(mean(x),length(x))), df$area)
#[1] 2.75 4.50 3.50 2.75 2.75 2.75 4.50 3.50
```

---

If we can install other packages, we can use either `dplyr` or `data.table`.

Using `dplyr`, we group by 'area', and create the 'avg' column with `mutate`.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(area) %>% 
   mutate(avg= mean(snakes))
```

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'area', we assign (`:=`) the `mean` of 'snakes' as the 'avg' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, avg:= mean(snakes), by = area]
```